# How to present a mixed result of two tables using subqueries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe the title of the question is not completly right. I will try explain better my issue.
I have two tables with following structure:

TABLE01:

```
ID | GENUS | SPECIES | INDIVIDUUM
 1 |     A |       a | alfa
 2 |     B |       b | beta
 3 |     C |       c | gama
 4 |     D |       d | delta
 5 |     E |       e | epsilon
```

TABLE02:

```
ID1 | ID2 | INDEX
  1 |   2 |   21%
  1 |   3 |   17%
  1 |   4 |   32%
  1 |   5 |   43%
  2 |   1 |   21%
  2 |   3 |   19%
  2 |   4 |   94%
  2 |   5 |   91%
  .     .       .
  .     .       .
  .     .       .
  5 |   1 |   43%
  5 |   2 |   91%
  5 |   3 |   83%
  5 |   4 |   76%
```

Than I do following select:

```
SELECT id FROM table01 WHERE individuum in (alfa,epsilon);
```

and receives following result:

```
| ID |
|  1 |
|  5 |
```

With that I do another select:

```
SELECT * FROM table02 WHERE ID1 in (1,5);
```

This time I receive, as you probably already know, the following result:

RESULT02:

```
ID1 | ID2 | INDEX
  1 |   2 |   21%
  1 |   3 |   17%
  1 |   4 |   32%
  1 |   5 |   43%
  5 |   1 |   43%
  5 |   2 |   91%
  5 |   3 |   83%
  5 |   4 |   76%
```

Now I would like to create a new table based on this results that would give me the following fields (and values):

```
id | individuum | species | genus | id2 | individuum2 | species2 | genus2 | index |
 1 |       alfa |       a |     A |   2 |        beta |        b |      B |   21% |
 1 |       alfa |       a |     A |   3 |        gama |        c |      C |   17% |
 1 |       alfa |       a |     A |   4 |       delta |        d |      D |   32% |
 1 |       alfa |       a |     A |   5 |     epsilon |        e |      E |   43% |
 5 |    epsilon |       e |     E |   1 |        alfa |        a |      A |   43% |
 5 |    epsilon |       e |     E |   2 |        beta |        b |      B |   91% |
 5 |    epsilon |       e |     E |   3 |        gama |        c |      C |   83% |
 5 |    epsilon |       e |     E |   4 |       delta |        d |      D |   76% |
```

It presents the data from the first table in an 'analytic' way that are somehow connected just like RESULT02 shows us in a 'synthetic' way.

I though in something like the following, but I am not sure that it is right.

```
SELECT
b.id1,
(SELECT a.individuum FROM table01 a WHERE id = a.id1) individuum,
(SELECT a.species FROM table01 a WHERE id = a.id1) species,
(SELECT a.genus FROM table01 a WHERE id = a.id1) genus,
b.id2,
(SELECT a.individuum FROM table01 a WHERE id = a.id2) individuum2,
(SELECT a.species FROM table01 a WHERE id = a.id2) species2,
(SELECT a.genus FROM table01 a WHERE id = a.id2) genus2,
b.index
FROM
    table02 b
WHERE
    individuum in (alfa , epsilon);
ORDER BY index DESC";
```

I would appreciate your help to create a better, faster and more efficient query.

Comment: Too many subselects... I'd think some JOINS would be much more efficient.

Comment: I beg to desagree, a simple join between tables would be better

Comment: You don't actually store '%' do you?

Comment: Frazz and Jorge Campos, I'm testing your solutions, but it' not working. I will write the problem under your respective answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Strawbery, don't worry, I don't store the '%'. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to see if this helps:

```
SELECT
  table01.id,
  table01.individuum,
  table01.species,
  table01.genus,
  -- -----------------
  table02.id as id2,
  -- -----------------
  t01.individuum as individuum2
  t01.species as species2, 
  t01.genus as genus2,
  -- -----------------
  table02.index
from
  table01
inner join
  table02 on table01.ID = table02.ID1
left join
  table01 as t01 on t01.ID = table02.ID2
where
    table01.individuum in (alfa , epsilon)
order by
  index DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Just rename (with aliases) the fields.

```
select
   t2.id, spec1.individuum, spec1.species, spec1.genus,
   t2.id2, spec2.individuum, spec2.species, spec2.genus
   t2.INDEX
from
    table2 t2 
    table1 spec1,
    table2 spec2
where t2.id1 = spec1.id
  and t2.id2 = spec2.id
```

Then you can add whatever condition you want like yours own `spec1.individuum in ('alfa','epsilon')` or `t2.id in (1,5)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
  t1a.*
  t1b.*
  t2.index
FROM table02 t2
JOIN table01 t1a ON t1a.id=t2.id1
JOIN table01 t1b ON t1b.id=t2.id1
WHERE t2.id1 IN (SELECT id FROM table01 WHERE individuum in (alfa,epsilon))
ORDER BY t2.index DESC
```

If you need to resolve column name conflicts explicitly, then you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  t1a.id,
  t1a.individuum,
  t1a.species,
  t1a.genus,
  t1b.id AS id2,
  t1b.individuum AS individuum2,
  t1b.species AS species2,
  t1b.genus AS genus2,
  t2.index
FROM table02 t2
JOIN table01 t1a ON t1a.id=t2.id1
JOIN table01 t1b ON t1b.id=t2.id1
WHERE t2.id1 IN (SELECT id FROM table01 WHERE individuum in (alfa,epsilon))
ORDER BY t2.index DESC
```